# C# Найти текст по шаблону на сайте, по примеру "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с кодом. 
Цель: найти текст по шаблону на сайте, по примеру "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.

Например: На сайте есть какой-то блог и среди него есть "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx". И надо среди этого всего найти именно "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx".

В "x" может быть как цифра, так и буква. Цифры могут быть большими и маленькими.
Например: "5ghJ7-hgFJ-748b-NKLO"

Comment: Что Вы пробовали, есть какие то наброски?

Comment: Подсказка автору: "регулярки! используйте регулярные выражения!" :)

Comment: Anton Komyshan, ничего ещё не пробовал. Не имею идей как реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение: `[a-zA-z0-9]{5}-[a-zA-z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-z0-9]{4}`

```
$reg = "[a-zA-z0-9]{5}-[a-zA-z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-z0-9]{4}";
string matchString = Regex.Match(stringToSearch, $reg).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли :)

Answer (score 0):

Этот паттерн выглядит красивее

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}(-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}){3}
```

Протестить можно [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/YWBavt/1)

Comment: Спасибо. Это тоже опробую)

Comment: @Spreeng К слову говоря, тот патерн неверный. В него можно вставить символы [\]^_`. Протестить можно тут https://regex101.com/r/11L1YX/1